# Phonegap upload image to server is not working

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, file-upload, phonegap

I tried to upload an image from my Android tablet to online server. However,it is not working and return me error code with 1 (alert: An error has occurred: Code = 1). Anyone got solution about this?

This is my js file

```
function uploadFromGallery() {

    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
                                function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                                { quality: 50,
                                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
                                );

}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'.jpeg';
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://serverurl/uploadImage.php"), win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

This is uploadImage.php

```
<?php 
 // Directory where uploaded images are saved
 $dirname = "image"; 
 // If uploading file
 if ($_FILES) {
    print_r($_FILES);
    mkdir ($dirname, 0777, true);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 }
?>
```

Comment: error 1 is file not found, can you check the imageURI?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I think I never set argument for uploadPhoto function in uploadFromGallery, do you know how to set the argument?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, is it the directory of folder which store the image?

Comment: you should get the argument from the camera success callback, what I mean is to log it so you can see if it looks good

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I tried to alert the imageURI out, it is garbled